# I want to pause and resume my program

Tags: java, wait, notify

I have a program that estimates the value of PI every million trials. However, I want the program to be paused when I click on pause and to resumes when I click on run, using `wait()` and `notify()`.

I must use multiple threads as well as a `Boolean` as a signal of where should it pause and run, but I do not know how. I am confused.

Any ideas?

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Ex03 extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    int n = 0;
    int c = 0;
    double Pi;
    int change = 1000000;
    boolean runing = true;

    JLabel actualpi = new JLabel("The Actual value of PI   " + Math.PI);
    JLabel estimation = new JLabel("Current Estimate:  ");
    JLabel tri = new JLabel("Number Of Trials:  " + n);
    JButton run = new JButton("Run");
    JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");

    public Ex03() {
        super("Ex 03");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        add(actualpi);
        add(estimation);
        add(tri);
        add(run);

        run.addActionListener(this);
        pause.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        if (e.getSource() == run) {
            thread.start();
            remove(run);
            add(pause);
        } else if (e.getSource() == pause) {
            remove(pause);
            add(run);
            try {
                thread.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        n++;
        while (runing) {
            double x = Math.random();
            double y = Math.random();
            if (((x * x) + (y * y)) <= 1)
                c++;
            n++;
            Pi = (4.0 * (double) c / n);

            if (n == change) {
                estimation.setText("Current Estimate:  " + Pi);
                tri.setText("Number Of Trials:  " + n);
                change = change + 1000000;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ex03();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use wait and notify. They're too low-level and hard to use well. Use a higher-level abstraction: a Condition, created from a Lock. Read the javadoc for examples. Note that your `runing` flag should be volatile to work. And it's useless, because you could just use interrupt() to interrupt the thread. Again, read the javadoc. Concurrency is a very hard topic. I would advise you to read Java concurrency in practice, because your simple example shows that you're missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: Inside you even listener you are creating *new* thread object every time user presses a button. This will not work you want to access already created thread to pause it. Create thread only once in class constructor and save it to field then use `wait` `notify` on that field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to do it in console application using Semaphore:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PiThread piThread = new PiThread();
        piThread.start();

        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String cmd;
        while ((cmd = bufferRead.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("write p to pause, r to resume, s to stop");

            switch (cmd) {
                case "p":
                    piThread.pauseComputation();
                    break;

                case "r":
                    piThread.resumeComputation();
                    break;

                case "s":
                    piThread.stopComputation();
                    piThread.join();
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class PiThread extends Thread {
        private volatile boolean stop = false;

        private volatile int total = 0;
        private volatile int insideCircle = 0;
        private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!stop) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    double x = Math.random();
                    double y = Math.random();

                    if (((x * x) + (y * y)) <= 1)
                        insideCircle++;

                    total++;
                }

                // using semaphores is slow
                try {
                    // not to garbage stdout
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                    semaphore.acquire();
                    semaphore.release();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // exit
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println("pi: " + getPiApproximation());
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }

        public void pauseComputation() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void resumeComputation() {
            semaphore.release();
        }

        public void stopComputation() {
            stop = true;
        }

        public double getPiApproximation() {
            return 4*(double)insideCircle / (double)total;
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be the best way to handle this in GUI but will give you a good start. The main idea is to use Semaphore to block worker thread. For this to work you must always call pauseComputation before resumeComputation otherwise there will be deadlock. After you call stopComputation you cannot resumeComputation or pauseComputation.